# Python: Invoke class & class methods by name with using eval

Tags: python, dynamic, reflection, python-2.6

```
class Test:
 @staticmethod
   def call():
     return
 def callMethod1():
    return
 def callMethod2():
    return
var methodName='Method1'
```

I want to invoke `callMethod1` or `callMethod2` in call() using `"call"+methodName()`. i.e, in php we do call any member using T`est->{"call".methodName}()` How can I achieve this in python without eval() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Test:
   @staticmethod
   def call(method):
      getattr(Test, method)()

   @staticmethod
   def method1():
      print('method1')

   @staticmethod
   def method2():
      print('method2')

Test.call("method1")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getattr` on the class to get the method.  I'm not sure how exactly to integrate it into your code, but perhaps this example will help:

```
def invoke(obj, methodSuffix):
    getattr(obj, 'call' + methodSuffix)()

x = Test()
invoke(x, 'Method1')
```

But you will have to add `self` as the first argument to your methods first.

Answer (score 0):

You should clean up your sample code, the indentation is broken and you don't have `self` on the methods.

Use `getattr(self, "call"+methodName)()`. Also the `call` method shouldn't be a staticmethod as it will need to access the class to call the other methods.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, methodName):
        self.methodName = methodName

    def call(self):
        return getattr(self, "call" + self.methodName, "defaultMethod")()

    def callMethod1(self): pass
    def callMethod2(self): pass
    def defaultMethod(self): pass

t = Test("Method1")
t.call()
```